# Laravel persisting data to database as null while return all statement displays correct data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Please I am new to Laravel 5.2, I have a form in which one of my select fields (`role_id`) is populated with data from my database roles table this works just fine. When returning the request and the data is returned perfectly:

```
{
    _token: "lKF7Inzy1sGnQ1DwX6yBZCqDjTpgcvqfBqANuInz",
    name: "jingle2",
    email: "jingle2@lodx.com",
    **role_id: "1",**
    is_active: "1",
    password: "jocoblinks",
    file: { }
}
```

But upon persisting the data on the form to the database, I in turn get a null value for this field.

Method for persisting data:

```
public function store(UserRequest $request)
{
    //return $request->all();

     User::create($request->all());

     return redirect('/admin/users');
}
```

This is what the field on my form looks like:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('role_id', 'Role:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('role_id', [0=>'Choose options'] + $roles, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

The `$roles` on the form is gotten from:

```
public function create()
{
    $roles = Role::lists('name', 'id')->all();

    return view('admin.users.create', compact('roles'));
}
```

Please I have tried to debug this but I don't really understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `role_id` column to the `fillable` variable. To do that, you need open your `User` model and add this field to protected variable `$fillable`. You can read about it in documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Thank you so much @MarekSkiba, I totally forgot about that. Adding `role_id` to the `fillable` variable made It work.